# Java: Не работает перевод строки. String в файл.txt

Tags: java, строки, файлы, javafx

При сохранении переменной `string` в файл txt, с помощью `FileChooser` пропадает перевод строки.
Поискав в гугле, нашел решение в виде замены `"\n"` на

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Однако даже это не помогло. Как и замена на "\r\n" и тому подобное
Сохранение в файл:

```
    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("txt files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
    fc.getExtensionFilters().add(filter);

    File file = fc.showSaveDialog(null);

    if (file != null) {
        try {
            PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(file.getAbsolutePath());
            write.print(OutputText); // где OutputText нужный мне string
            write.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
        ...
        }
    }
```

**UPD:** Так же, главное что было замечено, это то, что если использовать line-separator НО, в этом же классе. Например перед строчкой `write.print(OutputText);` добавить:

```
String OutputText = "awd"; 
OutputText += System..("line.."); //ну тут понятно
... и.т.д.
```

То, тогда все работает отлично! Но если я OutputText беру из другого класса, все портится. Хотя там реализовано все тем же сепаратором.

В чем возможна проблема? и куда стоит копать?

**UPD2:** OutputText формируется в другом классе, тем путем что к исходному OutputText (изначально пустому) += из результатов всяких функций которые возвращают string. Внутри функций используется тоже сепаратор.

java version "1.8.0_161"

Comment: Как формируется OutputText ? И какая версия Java? Лучше добавить эту информацию в вопрос